# click listview item go->new activity?

Tags: android, listview

hello i got a Listview Activity

```
public class fragment_main extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dersler);
        String[] myArray= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Dersler);
        ArrayAdapter<String> aad= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myArray);
        setListAdapter(aad);
    }

    private void setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter<String> aad) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    }
}
```

xml code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
   android:id="@+id/listder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
    android:entries="@array/Dersler">

</ListView>
```

i want to when i pressed `listview` `(string Matematik1)` when i pressed `string Matematik1` it will open `class.gnrl` like go other activity who can help me thanks for all !

Comment: Implement `onItemClick` event for `ListView`.

Comment: How can I do that give me a link or write me  short code ?

Comment: check this - http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ListView listview=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listder);


listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
 if (position == 0) {
        Intent int0 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), gnrl.class);
        startActivity(int0);
    }

    else if (position == 1) {
        Intent int1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), asf.class);
        startActivity(int1);
    }
    else if (position == 2) {
        Intent int2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ThirdActivity.class);
        startActivity(int2);
    }

    else if (position == 3) {
        Intent int3 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                FourthActivity.class);
        startActivity(int3);
    }


          }
        });
```

Comment: ooow its worked thanks robi !! :D i didn't sleep to 8 hours for it.thanks bro!

Comment: But I have to ask a question to u ? All items going same I don't wanting this <item>1 go gnrl.class item 2 go asf.class 3 go other class ? Hoe can I do this ?

Comment: use position for each item, like if position==1 then go for gnrl.class, and if position==2 then go for asf.class, Glad my answer help you. dont forget to accept my answer.

Comment: how can i do this can u write an exam like 3-4 lines  ?

Comment: Hey see my updated answer, if you have any doubt then fell free write a comment here. But you have to be more specific.

Comment: wow its working dude thanks all right :D but i wanna ask my last questions.
im clicking first item opening second listview and im clicking second listview item it will be open a webview can i add all command in Mainactivity ?

Answer (score 0):

Try out as below:

```
public class fragment_main extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dersler);
     ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listder);

      String[] myArray= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Dersler);
ArrayAdapter<String> aad= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myArray);

      list.setAdapter(aad);

       //Add the item click listener as below.
       list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
              Toast.makeText(YourListActivity.this,
                 "Item in position " + position + " clicked"+ myArray[position].toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

             Intent intent=new Intent(this,<yourclassname>.class);
              startActivity(intent);
          }
        });
}

private void setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter<String> aad) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but what is the item position am i write my item name ? (Matematik1) and clicked ? (Go gnrl.java) ? Excuse me I'm beginner here 

Comment: You can get your items position as `myArray[position].toString();` Check out my updated answer.

Comment: wwhat am i write there ? myArray[or here ?].toString("is here ?");

Comment: @user3529221 Please be clear for what do you want to get exactly?

Comment: i wrote down comment pls look here.im sorry excuse for me brother.

Answer (score 0):

```
 l1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) 
        {                       
           String name=(String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);  
       if(position==1)
       {                
           Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(),1st_class.class);
           i.putExtra("PROJECT", name);
           startActivity(i);
       }
       else if(position==2)
       {                
           Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(),2nd_class.class);
           i.putExtra("PROJECT", name);
           startActivity(i);
       }
       else if(position==2)
       {                
           Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(),3rd_class.class);
           i.putExtra("PROJECT", name);
           startActivity(i);
       }
        }
    });
```

Another activity

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String receivedName = (String) intent.getSerializableExtra("PROJECT");
```

Comment: i wrote this but its not working ? am i write anythink at "PROJECT" line  ?

Comment: PROJECT is an identifier,using this you can values in next activity

Comment: can u add me on skype(burqman01 hotm4il.c0m) or i can give team viewer pls help :S

Comment: i am going to office ,in india time i will meet 9 am in team viewer.

Comment: Oke  send me any post via e mail thanks for all I'm waiting your post ☺